# ドキュメントルートを維持したまま、別ディレクトリ (/opt/xxx) を公開する方法

Tags: apache

今まで `/var/www/html` で公開していたサイトを維持しながら
新しく `/opt/xxx` のディレクトリも公開したく思います。

調べてみたら httpd.conf の Alias を使えばできそうでしたが
Alias はルートディレクトリごと変更するみたいでした。

ルートディレクトリは維持したままにしたいので
いい方法がありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。どちらのやり方でもできました！！

Answer (score 1):

サブディレクトリとして公開するなら、手っ取り早くはシンボリックリンクを作成するのが簡単だと思います。

例: (Redmine でドキュメントルート以外のディレクトリを公開する手順)

```sh
$ cd /var/www/html
$ sudo ln -s /var/lib/redmine/public redmine
```

→ ブラウザからは `localhost/redmine` のような形式でアクセス可

注意点として、公開したい大元のディレクトリは web サーバのプロセス (アカウント) からアクセス可能な状態にしておく必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

ファイルシステムの操作ができない場面もあるかと思いますので、
`httpd.conf`のみで設定する方法もご紹介します。

こちらに近い例がありました
https://serverfault.com/questions/295975/add-a-directory-to-the-apache-web-root

```
Alias /opt-xxx /opt/xxx
<Directory /opt/xxx>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

このように書くことで、
`http://hoge.com/opt-xxx/file1.jpg`
-> `/opt/xxx/file1.jpg`
のようなアクセスが可能になります。